# Port PhpStorm settings (everything) from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: phpstorm

I am going to shift from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. I am using PhpStorm for my web development work and have configured everything as per my needs. I want to shift these settings to Ubuntu.

I have exported settings in Windows PhpStorm and it made a `.jar` file. I am unable to import `.jar` file in Ubuntu PhpStorm though.

Comment: If `File | Export/Import Settings` does not work .. try manual file copying. You may need to adjust some paths manually though... https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: "I am unable to import .jar file in Ubuntu PhpStorm though." Do you get an error or something?

Comment: There was no option to select the .jar file, I have shifted back to Windows though. I think I am not skilled enough to use Linux. I am keeping this question open, maybe someone other can get help from this.